# JPA or Hibernate - Joining tables on columns of different types

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

Is there a way to tell Hibernate to wrap a column in a to_char when using it to join to another table or conversely convert a NUMBER to a VARCHAR? I have a situation where I have a table which contains a generic key column of type VARCHAR which stores the Id of another table which is a Number. I am getting a SQL exception when Hibernate executes the SQL it generates which uses '=' to compare the two columns.

Thanks...

P.S. I know this is not ideal but I am stuck with the schema so I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should be possible using a formula in your many-to-one. From section [5.1.22. Column and formula elements](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column) (solution also mentioned in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183185/usertype-join-in-hibernate)):

> `column` and `formula` attributes can
>   even be combined within the same
>   property or association mapping to
>   express, for example, exotic join
>   conditions.
>
> ```
> <many-to-one name="homeAddress" class="Address"
>         insert="false" update="false">
>     <column name="person_id" not-null="true" length="10"/>
>     <formula>'MAILING'</formula>
> </many-to-one>
> ```

With annotations (if you are using Hibernate 3.5.0-Beta-2+, see [HHH-4382](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4382)):

```
@ManyToOne
@Formula(value="( select v_pipe_offerprice.offerprice_fk from v_pipe_offerprice where v_pipe_offerprice.id = id )")
public OfferPrice getOfferPrice() { return offerPrice; }
```

Or maybe check the `@JoinColumnsOrFormula`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(
{ @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="SUBSTR(product_idnf, 1, 3)", referencedColumnName="product_idnf")) })
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Product productFamily;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. the @JoinColumnsOrFormula annotation worked perfectly. You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: What does it mean "<formula>'MAILING'</formula>"?