# JPA define relationship on a field that requires type conversion

Tags: java, jpa, types, relationship

I want to join two tables on column "vendor", 
In invoice table vendor type is integer, in vendor table, vendor is type varchar(10).

Is it possible to do a type conversion and also have a relationship?

```
@Entity
public class Vendor
{
    private String id;

    @Id(Column="vendor")
    public String getId(){ ... }
}

@Entity
public class Invoice
{
    private Vendor vendor;

    @One-to-one
    public Vendor getVendor() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, using a pivot table (as you would do to represent a many-to-many relationship) would be the right way to do that.

Something like this should work:

```
@Entity
public class Invoice
{
    @JoinTable(name = "invoice_vendor", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "invoice", referencedColumnName = "vendor_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "vendor", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @OneToOne
    private Vendor vendor;
}
```

Where the invoice_vendor table has the integer id in id column and varchar reference in vendor_id column.

Also I surmise you would like a ManyToOne relationship between vendors, but you've written one to one, so I have left that as such.

Comment: Yes I suppose this will work, but I'm not happy with having an extra table. The reason I added a bounty is actually because I'd like to do aggregations like AVG() over a text field, and I assumed that the answer to this question will solve my problem too. I think @Transient will work, but I still have to test it. Thanks, I'll award the bounty to you if I don't get any better answers.

Comment: @AmanicA That solution would work for mapping a given type in the code to a differently typed column in the database (such as an enum field to a text column) but I don't think you can define a joincolumn that way. I am not sure if converters of EclipseLink or Hibernate work with relationships either, I'll experiment with that though..

Comment: Is it me or are you using a full table to emulate something as simple as a cast function? A proper answer should provide "f(x) = x + 1" and not a table of (0,1), (1,2), (2,3)... ad infinitum

Comment: That is what a pivot/join table is. The mapping is not that trivial given that the relationship there shouldn't have been one to one in the first place (if it were, the solution would be a foreign key and a join column on that).
And it most certainly isn't a context-free function like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be done using a transient field

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    ...
    private boolean isActive;
    ...
    @Transient
    public boolean getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }
    public void setIsActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }
    @Basic
    private String getIsActiveValue() {
        if (isActive) {
            return "T";
        } else {
            return "F";
        }
    }
    private void setIsActiveValue(String isActive) {
        this.isActive = "T".equals(isActive);
    }
}
```

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Conversion

Answer (score 0):

Which JPA provider do you use?

It seems that Hibernate has a separate annotation for this (@JoinColumnsOrFormula). To my knowledge, EclipseLink does not offer that annotation.

[See related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096985/jpa-or-hibernate-joining-tables-on-columns-of-different-types)