# Join columns of different types in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

I have 2 tables. Table1 has a column called 'id' which is a number. Table2 has a column called `entity_id` which is `varchar`. Table1 has one to Many relation with Table2.

Here is my Hibernate mapping for Table1

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Table1")
public class Table1 implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private List<Table2> notes;
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id= id;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity=Table2.class)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name="ENTITY_ID",referencedColumnName="ID")
    public List<Table2> getNotes() {
        return storeNotes;
    }
    public void setNotes(List<Table2> notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }
}
```

When I create a ctiteria with Table1 and try to list the data, I am getting Invalid number error because the type mismatch in the join column. can you please let me know how can I ast id to varchar?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096985/jpa-or-hibernate-joining-tables-on-columns-of-different-types

Comment: Types are here to help us write proper code not to hack around. You may want to consider redesign of your data structure.

Comment: Show the program which you have tried and show the complete stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience just case  entity_id to the specfic data type (entity_id::INTEGER) like below example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Table1")
public class Table1 implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private List<Table2> notes;
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id= id;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity=Table2.class)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name="entity_id::INTEGER",referencedColumnName="ID")
    public List<Table2> getNotes() {
        return storeNotes;
    }
    public void setNotes(List<Table2> notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why do You Want to choose that Kind of Design Where there is Type Mismatch?.Its a Best Practice to have consistent data type in POJO and Tables unless and until there is solid usecase for such exceptional scenario.

Comment: This is not an answer.